# inputenc does not works with \csvautotabular

Tags: tables, input-encodings, csvsimple

I have to download csv into tex document. I use `\csvautotable` and this function works, but when I try to use not english and include `inputenc` and `babel`, it does not works.
I must download data only into `tabular`, because I use `floatrow{picture;table}`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=10mm,bottom=20mm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=6,use comma,fixed,1000 sep={}}
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}    
    \csvautotabular{bookbook.csv}
\end{document}
```

Error to line with "\csvautotabular{bookbook.csv}":

```
! Argument of � has an extra }.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you show a small sample of the `.csv` file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by removing russian symbols from csv file's header.

Comment: @Zarko this comment seems misplaced (there are no other answers to accept)

Comment: indeed, I already remove it.